# Sorting specific elements in structure

Tags: c

I have a question about sorting elements in structure. If I have two structures:

```
typedef struct
{
    char name[25],surname[25];
    int number;
}PLAYER;

typedef struct
{
    char nameofteam[25];
    int numberofplayers;
    PLAYER *players;
}TEAM;
```

How to sort data about players in a team by ascending order of the numbers on the jersey `(int number)`? Prototype of function is `void sort(TEAM *)`.

This gives an error `.exe has stopped working`:

```
void sort(TEAM *p)
{

    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<p->numberofplayers-1;i++)
    for(j=i+1;j<p->numberofplayers;j++)
    if((p[i].players)->number > (p[j].players)->number)
    {
        TEAM temp=p[i];
        p[i]=p[j];
        p[j]=temp;
    }
}
```

The problem is that number on jersey `(int number)` isn't in structure `TEAM`.

When specific element for sorting is in structure, then the checking would go like this:

```
if(p[i].element > p[j].element)
```

Should I use dynamic allocation for `*players` in this function?

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: I think indexing `p->players[]` rather than `p[]` would do wonders for this algorithm, *regardless* of how `players` is allocated. Right now you're trying to sort multiple *teams* based on the number of their *first* player.

Comment: And you don't want to use `qsort`?

Comment: I always create my own functions, but if you have an idea with qsort, then let me know. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to sort the players, then the variable `temp` needs to be a `PLAYER *` and you need to swap players, not teams.  I must say that I'm not convinced that you've properly set up the `players` array in each team. Posting an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code logic is indexing off `p`, which is the *team* base pointer, not the *players* base pointer *within* the team. Everywhere you see this:

```
p[i]
```

should be this:

```
p->players[i]
```

Once that is addressed, the proper swap temp is required as well, which should be a `PLAYER`, not a `TEAM`

Something like this:

```
void sort(TEAM *p)
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0; i<p->numberofplayers-1; ++i)
    {
        for(j=i+1; j<p->numberofplayers; ++j)
        {
            if(p->players[i].number > p->players[j].number)
            {
                PLAYER tmp = p->players[i];
                p->players[i] = p->players[j];
                p->players[j] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All of this assuming you properly allocated the `players` member of the team, and `numberofplayers` accurately reflects that allocation.

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks. I just need to call it in main().

Comment: @NemanjaGrubor where you call it from makes no difference; the code itself was wrong. If a `TEAM` is properly set up, including properly setting up the `players` member and the `numberofplayers` member, what you see above is what is needed to sort players on the team. If it doesn't, then you have additional problems regardless, and I can all-but-guarantee you they're involved in player setup in one way or another.